# Error : This class should provide a default constructor (.....) [Instantiatable]

Tags: java, android, json, string

I am getting following Error:

> Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.mrad4tech.development.sportss.TwitterAPI)

```
[Instantiatable]

package com.mrad4tech.development.sportss;

public class TwitterAPI {

    private String twitterApiKey;
    private String twitterAPISecret;
    final static String TWITTER_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
    final static String TWITTER_STREAM_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";

    public TwitterAPI(String twitterAPIKey, String twitterApiSecret){
        this.twitterApiKey = twitterAPIKey;
        this.twitterAPISecret = twitterApiSecret;
    }

    ...
}
```

Help me please

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: What part of `a public constructor with no arguments` was not clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a default constructor to your class `TwitterAPI`.

```
//Default constructor takes no arguments
public TwitterAPI() { 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a no argument constructor:

```
public TwitterAPI(){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all, You should provide a default constructor.
Add this to your class:

```
public TwitterAPI() {

}
```